# O que é o pretérito mais-que-perfeito anterior do indicativo?

Tags: verbos, tempo-verbal, conjugações

Eu tinha visto essa conjugação no site 'https://conjugacao.reverso.net/conjugacao-portugues-verbo-colocar.html", e quando procurei seu significado, não o encontrei ou não o entendi. Peço a quem saiba para que explique, já o/a agradeço de antemão!

Exs.:

Eu tivera/houvera colocado;

Tu tiveras/houveras colocado;

Ele tivera/houvera colocado;

Nós tivéramos/houvéramos colocado;

Vós tivéreis/houvéreis colocado;

Eles tiveram/houveram colocado.

Chuto eu que é/seja (não sei qual) uma ação que já tinha acontecido no pretérito mais-que-perfeito, pois várias conjugações têm esse tipo de significado e pelo nome da própria conjugação ("anterior"); mas, ao mesmo tempo, acho que seriam conjugações demais relacionadas ao passado, mas, posso estar errado. Obrigado por teres me vista a dúvida!

Comment: Eu nem sabia que isso existia! O [Cibedúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/tempos-compostos/8349) lista-o mas não diz para que serve. Imagino que seja arcaísmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa perífrase verbal foi comum até ao século XIX, sendo usada com três funções muito distintas. A saber, é ou foi usada no lugar do:

**(A) Pretérito mais que perfeito do subjuntivo: *houvera bebido* = ’houvesse/tivesse bebido’**

> Sentia-se estranhamente maciço por dentro, como se **houvera bebido** gesso.
>   [Raul Pompeia (1863-95), O Ateneu](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Od5cAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT206&dq=%22como%20se%20houvera%20bebido%20gesso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqq8zA6OXoAhUjxoUKHdFSBGUQ6AEIPTAC#v=onepage&q=%22como%20se%20houvera%20bebido%20gesso%22&f=false)

**(B) Futuro do pretérito: *houvera gritado* = ’haveria/teria gritado’**

> […] se tivesse acontecido alguma desgraça, Ricardo **houvera gritado** por socorro.
>   [José de Alencar (1829-77), *Sonhos d’ouro*](https://digital.bbm.usp.br/bitstream/bbm/4657/1/000155-2_COMPLETO.pdf)

**(C) Pretérito mais que perfeito do indicativo: *houvera arriscado* = ’havia arriscado, arriscara’**

> sentia-se já arrependida do que **houvera arriscado**
>    ([Aluísio Azevedo](https://books.google.pt/books?id=eYBcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT35&dq=%22sentia-se%20j%C3%A1%20arrependida%20do%20que%20houvera%20arriscado%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiusoSv7-XoAhUPkxQKHWjPDmwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22sentia-se%20j%C3%A1%20arrependida%20do%20que%20houvera%20arriscado%22&f=false))

Depois do século XIX, esta perífrase verbal foi caindo em desuso, e os usos (A), de longe o mais comum no passado, e (B), raramente se encontram atualmente. Foi com muita dificuldade que encontrei estes exemplos (explicação minha entre colchetes):

> Se eu **houvera dito** [tivesse dito] isso, estaria liquidado.
>   [Anais do Senado Federal, 1994](https://books.google.pt/books?id=O19A9Wh9WdcC&q=%22houvera%20dito%22&dq=%22houvera%20dito%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr1vzbnuPoAhUfQkEAHc45BSIQ6AEIywEwEQ)
>
> A famosa biblioteca Real da Ajuda sumiu no incêndio de 1755. Se não, também **houvera vindo** [teria vindo].
>   [Antônio Bulhões, *Diário da cidade amada: Rio de Janeiro 1922*, v. II, 2015](https://books.google.pt/books?id=zAcsAAAAYAAJ&q=%22Se%20n%C3%A3o,%20tamb%C3%A9m%20houvera%20vindo%22&dq=%22Se%20n%C3%A3o,%20tamb%C3%A9m%20houvera%20vindo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUk_jGzuPoAhWxzoUKHabzBjkQ6AEIKDAA)

Já o uso (C) se encontra com alguma frequência em livros e imprensa recentes, mas praticamente só no Brasil. Alguns exemplos:

> o pai declarou falsamente que ele **houvera nascido** [tinha nascido] em 18 de julho de 1964
>   [Jornal do Commercio, Rio de Janeiro,8-9-2015](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=364568_20&pesq=%22houvera%20nascido%22&pasta=ano%20201)
>
> Eu dava risadas em casa, enquanto o tal comentarista engolia em seco o que **houvera dito** [tinha dito].
>   [Marcos Eduardo Neves, *Alex, a biografia*, 2015](https://books.google.pt/books?id=CDIQCwAAQBAJ&q=%22houvera%20dito%22&dq=%22houvera%20dito%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr1vzbnuPoAhUfQkEAHc45BSIQ6AEIPDAC)

### Que dizem as gramáticas?

As duas atuais que tenho em casa — *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Culnha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014)  e *Gramática do Português* (Gulbenkian, Lisboa, 2013) —  não dizem uma palavra sobre este tempo. Nas online, também não encontrei nada. Mas encontrei o uso (C) — ex. *houvera estudado* = ’tinha estudado’ — num Dicionário de conjugação de verbos de 1975 Bárbara Vasconcelos de Carvalho (excertos [1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Mais-que-perfeito%20composto:%20participio%20do%20verbo%20que%20se%20conjuga,%20com%20o%20imperfeito%20do%20indicativo%20dos%20auxiliares%22&sxsrf=ALeKk00Ciza-fuv0dFI0Y326bxLC9vXJ2g:1586710924312&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvxIToruPoAhVtA2MBHatWD10Q_AUoAXoECAIQCQ&biw=1366&bih=625) e [2](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qAIvAAAAYAAJ&q=Tamb%C3%A9m%20pode%20ser%20feita%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82&dq=Tamb%C3%A9m%20pode%20ser%20feita%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD-qq0rePoAhUAAGMBHThODPQQ6AEIKzAA)). A autora chama-lhe simplesmente “mais que perfeito composto”:

> b) Mais-que-perfeito composto: particípio do verbo que se conjuga, com o imperfeito do indicativo dos auxiliares — tinha estudado — havia estudado. Esta composição é a mais usada na linguagem moderna. Também pode ser feita com o mais-que-perfeito simples (tivera estudado — houvera estudado), porém superada hoje.

Entretanto os usos (A) e (B) — *houvera visto* significando ’houvesse visto’ e  ’haveria visto* — são parte de um fenómeno mais geral. Explicam a *Gramática do Português* (tomo I, p. 58) e a *Gramática Histórica da Lingua Portuguesa* (1931) de Said Ali ([p. 107 da 2ª parte](https://archive.org/details/M.saidAli.grammaticaHistoricaDaLinguaPorugueza/page/n395/mode/2up/search/formas+verbaes+em)) que o pretérito mais que perfeito simples do indicativo (p. ex. *ficara, perdera*), além da função que já tinha no latim, ganhou no português certas funções do imperfeito do subjuntivo (*houvesse, tivesse*, etc.) e do futuro do pretérito ou  condicional (*haveria, teria*). A *Gramática do Português* exemplifica com a passagem d’*Os Lusíadas* em que Camões diz que a “pequena Casa Lusitana” chegou a todo o lado e

> “se mais Mundo houvera, lá chegara”.

Em português atual diríamos que “se mais Mundo houvesse, lá chegaria”. Portanto, o que acontece é que *houvera/tivera* em perífrases verbais como  *houvera/tiver visto* pode estar a fazer o papel de *houvesse/tivesse* (uso A) ou de *haveria/teria* (uso B).

### Conclusão

O chamado pretérito mais que perfeito anterior (p. ex., *houvera visto*) é simplesmente forma alternativa do pretérito mais que perfeito do subjuntivo/conjuntivo (*houvesse visto*) do condicional composto/futuro do pretérito mais que perfeito (*haveria visto*) — formas que caíram em desuso — ou do pretérito mais que perfeito do indicativo (*havia visto, vira*), uso que ainda se vê na literatura e imprensa brasileira recentes. A minha impressão é que o uso recente é uma imitação deliberada da linguagem antiga, já que eu nunca ouvi ninguém, português ou brasileiro, falar assim.

### E para curiosos, aqui ficam mais exemplos, antigos e modernos

Como não encontrei nada isto explicado em nenhuma gramática (presumivelmente os gramáticos deram isto por extinto) e formei o meu entendimento na observação de montes de exemplos, e já que me dei ao trabalho de apontar muitos deles, aqui ficam mais alguns.

> Dessa feita, estava montado num cavalo muito bom, esquipador, que **houvera comprado** [tinha comprado] recentemente
>   [Elces Sampaio, *De mundo até aqui*, 2019](https://books.google.pt/books?id=3ZueDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT134&dq=%22houvera%20comprado%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOubaZnOPoAhUuxYUKHQSrB70Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22houvera%20comprado%22&f=false)
>
> Dir-se-ia que, afinal, teria encontrado a sua turma da qual se **houvera perdido** [tinha perdido] nos ínvios e inconstantes caminhos da rasteira política de interesses.
>   [Jornal do Commercio, Rio de Janeiro, 14-4-2016](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=364568_20&pesq=%22houvera%20perdido%22&pasta=ano%20201)
>
> Estive com o [César] de Campos, que me mostrou a nota recolhida acerca das duas agências. Disse-me que já **houvera pedido** [tinha pedido] de transferência
>   [Machado de Assis (1839 – 1908), *Obra Completa*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=05hUAAAAMAAJ&q=%22j%C3%A1%20houvera%20pedido%20de%20transfer%C3%AAncia%22&dq=%22j%C3%A1%20houvera%20pedido%20de%20transfer%C3%AAncia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz9fLKmuboAhVFLBoKHcB2A9kQ6AEIMjAB)
>
> Simeão acabava de contar dezenove anos e nunca **houvera sofrido** [havia sofrido] castigo algum corporal
>   [Joaquim Manuel Macedo, *Vítimas-Algozes*, 1869](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gYdcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT16&lpg=PT16&dq=%22nunca%20houvera%20sofrido%20castigo%22&source=bl&ots=SuDyKcMq9Q&sig=ACfU3U0UeVf6hEZcCzg0cIh_JKeqWZ8B_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv76r0meboAhUiA2MBHT7ZBmwQ6AEwAHoECAcQKQ#v=onepage&q=%22nunca%20houvera%20sofrido%20castigo%22&f=false)
>
> Já vi tudo o que havia de ver n’esta vida e prouvera a Deus que não **tivera visto** [tivesse visto] tanto.
>   [Pe. António Vieira (1608 – 97), *O Chrysostomo portuguez*, 1879.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=5PYRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA385&dq=%22tivera%20visto%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd1tXC_dvoAhXPxYUKHZD_CgUQ6AEIcDAH#v=onepage&q=%22tivera%20visto%22&f=false)
>
> Esta passagem seria hoje inintelligivel, se não **houveramos estudado** [tivéssemos estudado] o modo de ser das classes inferiores fóra dos municipios.
>   [Alexandre Herculano (1810 – 77), *História de Portugal*, tomo IV, Lisboa 1853, p. 78.](https://archive.org/details/historiadeport04herc/page/78/mode/2up/search/inintelligivel+se+n%C3%A3o)
>
> Se te vem a dizer que algum ha fallado mal de ti ; responde sómente , que naõ sabe todos teus vícios : porque **houvera dito** mais , se o **houvera conhecido** [teria dito mais, se o tivesse conhecido]
>   [Diogo Guerreiro Camacho de Aboim (1658 – 1709), Escola Moral, Política, Cristã e Jurídica, Lisboa, 1759](https://books.google.pt/books?id=huY-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA480&dq=%22houvera%20dito%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbstiv_9roAhUEzIUKHSt3C3IQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22houvera%20dito%22&f=false)
>
> […] attesta a grande massa de riquezas que já **houvéramos colhido** [teríamos colhido], si tivéssemos logrado explorar por esse meio os nossos admiráveis recursos
>   [*Anais do Parlamento Brazileiro*, Rio de Janeior, 1887](https://books.google.pt/books?id=A9G6q92Oc98C&q=%22j%C3%A1%20houveramos%20colhido%22&dq=%22j%C3%A1%20houveramos%20colhido%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5irmNh9zoAhWKDWMBHXDiAN0Q6AEIKjAA)

E afinal o [princípio de Peter (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_de_Peter) já houvera sido descoberto por um português no século XVII:

> Quantos por falta de modestia vemos em cargos superiores à sua capacidade; que se **houveraõ ficado** [tivessem ficado] nos menores, e elegido estado adequado a seu talento, nem elles **foraõ** [seriam] mal reputados, nem o Reyno mal servido.
>   [Diogo Guerreiro Camacho de Aboim (1658 – 1709), Escola Moral, Política, Cristã e Jurídica, Lisboa, 1759, p. 404](https://books.google.pt/books?id=huY-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA404&lpg=PA404&dq=%22Quantos%20por%20falta%22&source=bl&ots=oJA-nPw_yu&sig=ACfU3U3xg4GmZpCi2T5BhTD4-aQUpBzhzA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMpvHeruboAhUGBGMBHTduCXIQ6AEwAnoECBEQOQ#v=onepage&q=%22Quantos%20por%20falta%22&f=false)

Comment: @Schilive, bem tu aceitaste a resposta, na altura. Portanto deves ter lido, não? Irias aceitar sem ler? E a aceitação já é agradecimento suficiente :)

Comment: Jacinto, então. Existe a força mor da preguiça, eu não li. Apenas aceitei porque a outra se mostrou errada e a tua tinha fundamento.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, o pretérito mais-que-perfeito é usado para um fato que ocorreu anterior a um outro fato também no passado.

Exemplo:

```
Ontem, Diogo mencionou que bebera uma bebida muito forte no mês passado. (pretérito mais-que-perfeito simples)
Ontem, Diogo mencionou que tinha bebido uma bebida muito forte no mês passado. (pretérito mais-que-perfeito composto)
```

As duas frases acima transmitem exatamente a mesma ideia.

Não consegui achar um material de referência, mas a minha intuição como nativo é que o pretérito mais-que-perfeito anterior adiciona uma camada a mais na sequência temporal, além do pretérito-mais-que-perfeito. Dado isso, eis uma situação que suponho válida para o uso do pretérito mais-que-perfeito anterior.

Exemplo:

```
[Dia 1] Diogo para Beatriz: "Bebi muito ontem" 

[Dia 2] Beatriz para Ana: "Diogo me disse que tinha bebido [bebera] muito anteontem"

[Dia 3] Ana para Márcio: "Beatriz me contou que Diogo tivera bebido muito"
```

Uma observação a ser feita é que no português falado o pretérito mais-que-perfeito nas formas simples e anterior é raramente utilizado e demasiadamente formal, sendo mais comum no português escrito, como em obras literárias por exemplo. Porém, na forma composta é usado recorrentemente tanto no português falado, quanto no escrito.

Comment: Então, é algo que se repete no passado do pretérito mais-que-perfeito até o pretérito perfeito? Eu lhes vi a diferença no https://www.conjugacao.com.br/preterito-perfeito-composto-do-indicativo/. Eu estou tentando colocá-los numa linha temporal.

Comment: Editei minha resposta para explicar melhor. A ideia não seria de repetição, mas sim de uma camada a mais numa linha temporal. Como mencionei, não tenho absoluta certeza disso, mas é o que faz mais sentido como nativo.

Comment: Enzo e @Schilive, nunca vi ou ouvi o uso que o Enzo sugere. O que eu encontrei na literatura, exemplificando com o verbo *ver*, foi *houvera visto* com o significado de ’houvesse/tivesse visto’, ’haveria/teria visto’ ou simplesmente de ’havia/tinha visto’. Tipo: "se João houvera chegado (= tivesse chegado) mais cedo, ainda houvera visto (= teria visto) a irmã". Isto era comum até ao século XIX, depois desaparece. Posso escrever uma resposta, mas vou precisar de tempo.

Comment: @Jacinto, eu conheço essa forma e acho que ambos os significados têm valor, o dito por Enzo Nakamura e por ti; o de Enzo seria provavelmente o quê nativos entenderiam e o teu, como é/era usado. Acho que se escreveres tua resposta, deves pelo menos mencionar essa, mas ser-te-ia a resposta.

Comment: @Schilive, eu também sou falante nativo. A diferença é que eu formei o meu entendimento a partir de exemplos reais que encontrei em livros e jornais; exemplos antigos e atuais.

Comment: Enzo, no teu exemplo do dia 3, é perfeitamente correto dizer "Beatriz me contou que Diogo bebera/tinha bebido muito". O mais-que-perfeito simplesmente indica que  'Diogo beber' ocorreu antes da ação passada "Beatriz contar". Por outro lado, em exemplos reais como "César dos Campos [...] disse-me que já houvera pedido" ou "engolia em seco o que houvera dito", não é possível encontrar nenhuma "camada temporal" extra -- é novamente uma ação anterior a outra ação passada (disse, engolia). Isto mostra que mais-que perfeito = mais-que-perfeito anterior. >>

Comment: >>A diferença é a que tu observas no fim: coisas como *tinha visto* são de uso universal; *vira* e *houvera visto* é mais formal e literário, e, diria eu, *houvera visto* é arcaizante.

Comment: @Jacinto, entendi, muito obrigado pela explicação. Ao meu ver, adicionar uma camada extra era o que fazia sentido para mim, pois não vejo muita lógica na existência de uma conjugação a mais. Você sabe dizer o propósito desta existência?

Comment: Enzo, não sei se alguma vez houve propósito. Imagino que os nossos tataravós foram ao longo dos séculos inventando novas formas de se exprimirem.Afinal nós já sabíamos de *vira* e *tinha visto*, que também são duplicatas. Se vires a minha resposta, *houvera visto* é "duplicata" também de *tivesse visto* e *teria visto*. Em Portugal, coloquialmente o pessoal usa o imperfeito em vez do futuro do pretérito (*gostava de ir ao Brasil*, formalmente *gostaria e ir ao Brasil*). No passado podias dizer "tenho escrito uma carta" = "escrevi um carta". A língua foi sempre mudando.

Comment: É claro que tu podias ter três momentos explicitamente (se calhar era isso que querias): "Beatriz me contou que Diogo lhe dissera que houvera bebido muito". Mas eu não vi nenhum exemplo deste tipo (todos os caso que vi tinham só dois momentos; e se tivesses quatro?). A maneira natural para mim de dizer isto seria: "Beatriz me contou que Diogo lhe disse que tinha bebido muito" .